# hibernate from onetomany to manytomany avoiding loops

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

i have 6 main tables related to each other in a loop 
table 1 is elated to table 2 
table 2 to table 3

.

.

.

table 5 to table 6

and table 6 to table 1

they all hova a manytomany relationship except the relation between 6 and 1 is onetomany

table 6 has the primary key of table 1 as foreign key

now the problem is i need to change this relation to a manytomany relationship

i am using lazy fetch type which can cause loops of queries the never end.

and i can't find a technical solution for that.

thak you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@i am using lazy fetch type which can cause loops of queries the never end .. 
If you use lazy fetch, you will not have any problems since the relationship entities will be fetched only on demand.

And, You can read about Bidrectional relationship. Make a manyTomany relation ship from Entity6 to Entity1 and use mappedBy in Entity1 so that it'll act as bidirectional.